# Respect unit scale when linking or appending objects

Tags: units, append

Appending/linking the same object with the same metric size from Blender files with different unit scales in Blender 2.8 results in objects of different sizes. It seems, Blender respects only the internal Blender units when appending/linking an object and ignores the unit scale.

Is there a way to force Blender to respect unit scale when appending objects?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new scene and change the unit scale from 1 to 0.1 in the scene properties.
2. Add a default cube with size 2m.
3. Save the file and create a new scene.
4. In the new scene leave the unit scale at the default setting of 1.
5. Append the cube from the other file. The cube will now have a size of 20m. I would have expected it to have a size of 2m.

Comment: Hello :). Blender respects the scale of your target scene. In your example, Blender just multiplies the *source scale* (0,1) by 10 to match the *target scale* (1,0). To keep linked objects the same size, you need to keep uniform unit scale across linked files.

Comment: That's what I suspected. But isn't this totally impractical? I can imagine scenarios in which I want to use assets which were created in another scale. Do I have to rescale such assets before every use?

Comment: Honestly, I can't think of a good reason to change the [default unit scale](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/scene/properties.html#units) of 1. I only change units *km>meters>milimeters* which doesn't affect linking/appending in any way. Would you mind sharing your reasons for changing the unit scale? :)

Comment: Well, my answer was almost completely written, when your comment got me thinking again… For my current hard surface workflow changing the unit type will indeed probably be enough. It's just about better handling of small values in modifiers. Thanks for the indirect hint! ;)
There is one other possible use case, untested by me though: Physics simulations seem often to have problems with small objects (at least that is my experience, but I don' really know what I'm doing, so…). I could imagine working with bigger blender units could be advantageous in these areas.

Comment: You're right about physics simulations, they often work better at larger sizes. But unit scale is ignored in simulations, so it's of no help there. Good luck with your project :).

Comment: Thanks :). One question regarding physics simulations, though: Blender's physics engines always work with Blender units, right? So an object of the size of 2cm in unit scale 0.1 would be as big as an object of the size of 20 cm in unit scale 1.0. But they both would have the same size in Blender's own/internal unit system.
Or in other words: Changing the unit scale should result in different object sizes in Blender's own unit system. So wouldn't this affect the physics simulations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102963/discussion-between-customizer-and--).